# "get_data_yahoo" from "pandas_datareader" returns empty DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I was trying to fetch stock data using the "get_data_yahoo" method from "pandas_datareader" so I wrote the following to test it out. I learned that there have been problems with the Yahoo API so I followed the instruction [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fix-yahoo-finance) to add the "fix_yahoo_finance" module and `yf.pdr_override()`.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
from datetime import datetime

yf.pdr_override()
a = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start=datetime(2017, 8, 13), end=datetime(2017, 8, 14))
b = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AMZN', start=datetime(2017, 8, 13), end=datetime(2017, 8, 14))
c = pdr.get_data_yahoo('MSFT', start=datetime(2017, 8, 13), end=datetime(2017, 8, 14))
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

However, when I ran the above code, sometimes the stocks could not be fetched and that resulted in one or two of the DataFrame (or all three) being empyty as shown below.
[image]
[image]
In the first picture only the first one is fetched while in the second picture only the second is fetched.
I tried out different tickers and ran many times and this seems to be a random pattern. Does anyone know what's going on? Is it the module broken again or something I can fix on my end? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can't diagnose the exact issue happening here right now but here is a workaround:

```
stock_list = ['AMZN', 'MSFT', 'AAPL']
stock_dict = {}
for stock in stock_list:
    dim = (0,0)
    while dim != (1,6):
       s = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start="2017-08-13",end="2017-08-14")
       dim = s.shape
    stock_dict[stock] = s
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
stocks = [stock + '.AX' for stock in stockList]*
```

before calling

```
pdr.get_data_yahoo(**stocks**, start="2017-08-13",end="2017-08-14")
```